# group by the count of how many successive days per id in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

If I have a pandas df like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "id":[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4],
     "date":("2000-07-06","2000-07-07","2000-07-08","2000-07-09","2000-07-10","2000-07-06","2000-07-10","2000-07-11","2000-07-17","2000-07-20","2000-07-06","2000-07-07","2000-07-08","2000-07-10","2000-07-15","2000-07-16","2000-07-25","2000-07-11","2000-07-20")})
df.date =pd.to_datetime(df.date)

         date     id
1   2000-07-06     1
2   2000-07-07     1
3   2000-07-08     1
4   2000-07-09     1
5   2000-07-10     1
6   2000-07-06     2
7   2000-07-10     2
8   2000-07-11     2
9   2000-07-17     2
10  2000-07-20     2
11  2000-07-06     3
12  2000-07-07     3
13  2000-07-08     3
14  2000-07-10     3
15  2000-07-15     3
16  2000-07-16     3
17  2000-07-25     3
18  2000-07-11     4
19  2000-07-20     4
```

and I would like to group by the id, but counting how many times there was successive days for each id, in order to expect something like that:

```
   count     id
1    4        1
2    1        2
3    3        3
3    0        4
```

I dont know if building a loop will be the best option, but I would like to know if someone knows a fast approach or a function that can do that. Thanks

Comment: Always add the pandas tag to a pandas question. Your question will get answered much quicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and conditionally fill `1` or `0` if the difference is `1 day` with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). After that sum the total of `1's` :

```
df['diff'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['date'].diff() == '1 days', 1, 0)

df_grouped = df.groupby('id').diff.sum()
```

**output**

```
print(df_grouped.reset_index().rename({'diff':'count'}, axis=1))
   id  count
0   1      4
1   2      1
2   3      3
3   4      0
```

Or you can use `.agg`:

```
df_grouped2 = df.groupby('id').agg({'diff':'sum'})

print(df_grouped2.reset_index().rename({'diff':'count'}, axis=1))
   id  count
0   1      4
1   2      1
2   3      3
3   4      0
```